# No outlook webhook notification for events in secondary calendars

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

I have successfully [subscribed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations) to changes of the events resource with a request body of:

> ```
> {
>   "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
>   "Resource": "me/events",
>   "NotificationURL": "...",
>   "ChangeType": "Created, Updated, Deleted"
> }
> ```

Although I get the expected webhook notification when modifying an event in the user's default calendar, I don't get any webhook notifications when modifying events in other calendars of the same user.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug or just an undocumented behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To subscribe the notification of other calendars, you need to change the the "Resource" to "me/calendars/{calendar_id}/events".

GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars

[image]

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
  "Resource": "me/calendars/{calendar_id}/events",
  "NotificationURL": "...",
  "ChangeType": "Created, Updated, Deleted"
}
```